# I want to implement UART module in Xilinx with Encryption functionality so which algorithm i shuld choose RSA or AES

Tags: encryption

i designed code for uart module now i want to include Encryption code before sending the data which algorithm is better for me RSA or AES

Comment: Your Post is entirely an opinion based unless you mention your modules requirements and constraints

Comment: The fact that you are asking for a choice between RSA and AES is a clear indication that you, personally, should do neither.

Answer (score 4):

Since RSA and AES do very different things, neither of which being what you imagine it is, I would say that your question cannot be answered with anything remotely equivalent to the cold rationality of mathematics. As an analogy, in a different context, your question would be: "I have a car and I want to make it faster; should I paint it red or blue ?". The only answer, then, is: "blue is cooler". Any half-witted buffoon can drive a red car, but it takes class and dignity to assume a blue vehicle. Similarly, implementing AES on a FPGA is easy. RSA, now, that's a challenge. Use RSA to demonstrate your abilities. Yeah, that man can do RSA on a FPGA ! That ought to woo chicks.

---

Nevertheless, if you want to "do encryption", then the first thing to determine is **why**. Encryption is *communication*: you encrypt data because:

- You don't want outsiders to be able to access the data while it is stored or transferred;
- *but* you do want the data to be accessed somewhere in space-time, by "someone".

Encryption transfers the confidentiality issue into *key management*. With encryption, the power to read gigabytes of data reduces to the knowledge of the decryption key. It makes no sense to "encrypt" data in your circuit if there is nobody to decrypt it afterwards; otherwise, why would you send it at all ? But if there *is* somebody, then there is some decryption key, and at that point RSA and AES become very different from each other.

AES is **symmetric encryption**: the key to encrypt, and the key to decrypt, are identical. This works in contexts where it is possible for whoever sends the data, and whoever is supposed to receive it, to *share* a common secret value. Symmetric key management is hard, because it is not easy to *securely* transfer secret keys between people, unless they physically meet at some point.

RSA is **asymmetric encryption**: the key to encrypt and the key to decrypt are mathematically linked to each other, but different. The decryption key cannot (realistically) be recomputed from the encryption key, so the encryption key can be made public: this does not reveal the private key. Asymmetric encryption makes key management easier: only public keys need to be exchanged, and since they are public, this can be done in a relatively careless way. But asymmetric encryption requires a lot more mathematics, and is heavier (and that's why stuffing RSA into a FPGA is a complex endeavour).

Moreover, RSA encrypts only short messages (typically at most 117 bytes for a 1024-bit RSA key), so it cannot easily replace AES. In other words, AES does things that RSA cannot do, and RSA does things that AES cannot do. Therefore, there is no absolute answer about which one you should use, out of any context.

Except, of course, that RSA is cooler.

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on your requirements, but the usual scheme used in e.g. TLS and PGP/GPG is to generate an AES key (called the session key), encrypt that with RSA. Send the encrypted session key first, followed by a stream of data encrypted with the session key.

This provides both mutual authentication (i.e. provided you know the RSA keys in advance) which prevents man-in-the-middle-attacks and forward secrecy as long as you make sure the session key gets lost when the session's over.

Another reason for using such a combined scheme: RSA is usually much slower than AES. But given that AES is symmetric where RSA is assymetric, if for your usecase presharing the decryption key isn't an option RSA removes the need for that.

Additionally you might want to have a look at [Hybrid encryption with RSA and AES versus splitting into multiple RSA messages](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10685/hybrid-encryption-with-rsa-and-aes-versus-spliting-into-multiple-rsa-messages%5d.)